# How to change focus from left window to right window or to refresh the browser using a shortcut

Tags: shortcuts

I am a software developer and I have on my left pane VS code and on the right pane I have firefox.

Is it possible to e.g. reload the currently active browser tab using a shortcut without changing the focus from my vs code?

How about if I want to quickly search something and want to jump to the browser without using the mouse or say using super+tab to find the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does not expose a command line interface to **refresh the currently displayed page**. Directly interacting with Firefox through a system wide hotkey to refresh a page therefore is not possible.

Still, you could set up a small script with automation tools that, when activated with a a shortcut key, would briefly switch to firefox, press F5 there and then switch back to the previous application. You could achieve this with only `xdotool`. It can switch to a specific window (just like `wmctrl` mentioned below) and simulate keystrokes. Simulating an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> keystroke would switch you back to the previous window.

**Jumping to the browser** with a single shortcut key is already build in in a standard Ubuntu desktop. If you have your browser on the dock in for example the first position, then <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> will immediately switch you to the browser. If using Firefox, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> to move to the URL bar and type your search. When done, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> to return to your previous window.

In any desktop, the following oneliner will work to set up a hotkey that switches to Firefox, or launches it if not already running.

```
sh -c "wmctrl -x -a Firefox || firefox"
```

A solution on steroids, based on the same principle, is provided by the utility [jumpapp](https://github.com/mkropat/jumpapp).

Answer (score 0):

for other ubuntu based distros try @vanadium answer but first install

**sudo apt install wmctrl**

then

**sh -c "wmctrl -x -a terminal || Terminal"**

Comment: how does this help/why is this important? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1410817/edit) to add more details to your answer.